# Mysql Transactions and balances

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

So I have this table in MySQL with user information:

```
[             USERS           ]
[id | name |  email  | balance]
[ 1 | A    | a@e.com |    0   ]
[ 2 | B    | b@e.com |    0   ]
[ 3 | C    | c@e.com |    0   ]
```

and a table with transactions

```
[           TRANSACTIONS         ]
[id | user_id | product |  amount  | price ]
[ 1 |       3 |TV 600   |       1  | 279,22]
[ 2 |       2 |Radio G  |       1  |  32,12]
```

What I want that if I add a row in the table `transactions`, that the `balance` of the user is also updated. What is the best practice to do it to make 100% sure that the balance is always right?

Stored procedure with lock or triggers or something else?

Comment: Go with triggers. Or computed column. Or a view.

Comment: Cumputed column might be slow when the amount of transactions grow I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a view for that task. Up-to-date data is guaranteed, as when querying view, the query behind it is executed, so it recalculates your balances.

```
create view MyCalculatedView as
select u.id, u.name, u.email, t.balance from USERS u
left join (
    select user_id, sum(price) as balance
    from TRANSACTIONS
    group by user_id
) t on u.id = t.user_id;
```

Comment: I thought of that too, however the table can contain out of 100k's of rows. I'm afraid it will become slow over time. Instead of calculating the result every time I need it, I think it is better to do the calculation on inserting data (calculates once). As just reading a balance field is so much quicker.

Comment: @NLAnaconda Well, trigger is also acceptable. But my approach with appropriate indexes should perform reasonably.

Comment: I think you are right. Should preform good enough. It has always the right balance and because that is most important I think I stick to this approach.

Comment: @NLAnaconda If you find my answer as helpful or solving your problem, you should accept the answer and optionally upvote.